# Posting JSON with jquery ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a simple php file that decode my json string, passed with ajax, and stamp the result, but I can't keep the `$_POST` variable, why???

I try to inspect with fireBug and I can see that the POST request is sent correctly, when the **php** script is called, he respond Noooooooob to me, it seem any POST variable is set.

All I want is to have my array =)

JSON String generated by `JSON.stringify`:

```
[
   {
      "id":21,
      "children":[
         {
            "id":196
         },
         {
            "id":195
         },
         {
            "id":49
         },
         {
            "id":194
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":29,
      "children":[
         {
            "id":184
         },
         {
            "id":152
         }
      ]
   },
   ...
]
```

JavaScript

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  var tmp = JSON.stringify($('.dd').nestable('serialize'));
  // tmp value: [{"id":21,"children":[{"id":196},{"id":195},{"id":49},{"id":194}]},{"id":29,"children":[{"id":184},{"id":152}]},...]
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'save_categories.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'categories': tmp},
    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
});
```

save_categories.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['categories'])) {
    $json = $_POST['categories'];
    var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
  } else {
    echo "Noooooooob";
  }
?>
```

Comment: and firebug that's what you're sending in query string parameters?

Comment: firebug tell me that the categories parameter is correctly passed, but when I access the $_POST it can't find.

Comment: remove the line echo "Noooooooob". :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your code works if you remove `dataType: 'json'`, just tested it.

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  var tmp = JSON.stringify($('.dd').nestable('serialize'));
  // tmp value: [{"id":21,"children":[{"id":196},{"id":195},{"id":49},{"id":194}]},{"id":29,"children":[{"id":184},{"id":152}]},...]
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'save_categories.php',
    data: {'categories': tmp},
    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This solution do exactly what i mean, thanks a lot @melc, I also add a preventDefault() because I used an <a href="..." html tag and it refresh the page without the result.

Answer (score 5):

it's work for me you can try this. 
JavaScript

`$('#save').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'save_categories.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({'categories': $('.dd').nestable('serialize')}),
    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
});`

you need to write the below code on save_categories.php 
   $_POST is pre-populated with form data.

> To get JSON data (or any raw input), use php://input.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$categories = $json->categories;
```

Comment: I think this should be the answer, specially for the php part. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

dataType is json, so jQuery posts this:

```
{"categories":"[{\"id\":21,\"children\":[{\"id\":196},{\"id\":195},{\"id\":49},{\"id\":194}]},{\"id\":29,\"children\":[{\"id\":184},{\"id\":152}]},...]"}
```

This is not standard urlencoded, so $_POST is empty.

You can set data to your complex structure, and jQuery will correctly encode it:

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'save_categories.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('.dd').nestable('serialize'),
    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
});
```

And in php: `$categories = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  var tmp = JSON.stringify($('.dd').nestable('serialize'));
  // tmp value: [{"id":21,"children":[{"id":196},{"id":195},{"id":49},{"id":194}]},{"id":29,"children":[{"id":184},{"id":152}]},...]
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'save_categories.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'categories=' + encodeURIComponent(tmp),
    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
});
```

I changed just this line:

```
data: 'categories=' + encodeURIComponent(tmp),
```

because thats the way, how you have to write data there. I tested it, its working...

Comment: This is no different than the ops code. jQuery will convert the object to a string just like you have anyway. The crucial part was probably the URL encoding and not passing the data property as a string.