# Export iCal Calendar with jquery ajax won't download ICS file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, calendar

I'm trying to save iCal Calendar's ICS file with AJAX.

The problem is that a need to pass many variables, and I saw in many places I have to do something like this, but I don't know where, and if I do so, the variables don't pass thru.

// window.location.href='phpToICS.php';
    // document.location.href='phpToICS.php';

this is my code:

```
function addToExternalCalendar(Bid,bid,pax,type,timeStamp,stampEnd,timeIn){ //exportexportcal
    $.post('phpToICS.php',
      {
        Bid:Bid,
        bid:bid,
        pax:pax,
        bType:type,
        timeStamp:timeStamp,
        stampEnd:stampEnd,
        timeIn:timeIn
      },
    function(data,status){
        if(status=="success"){
            // window.location.href='phpToICS.php';
            // document.location.href='phpToICS.php';
            jAlert("Exported Succesfully","Success");
        }else if(status=="error"){
            jAlert("Error EXPORT Failed","Failure");
        }
      });
}
```

UPDATED CODE WITH SUGGESTIONS:

```
function addToExternalCalendar(Bid,bid,pax,type,timeStamp,stampEnd,timeIn){ //exportexportcal
if(stampEnd==undefined){var stampEnd=timeStamp;}
    $.post('phpToICS.php',
      {
      // data: { Bid:Bid, bid:bid, pax:pax, bType:type, timeStamp:timeStamp, stampEnd:stampEnd, timeIn:timeIn },
        Bid:Bid,
        bid:bid,
        pax:pax,
        bType:type,
        timeStamp:timeStamp,
        stampEnd:stampEnd,
        dataType: 'script', // NONE OF THE OPTIONS WORK: "xml", "html", "text", "script", "json", "jsonp" //
        timeIn:timeIn
      },
// datatype: function(data,status){... } or datatype: function(response,type){... }
// THESE 2 STOP THE SCRIPT
    function(data,status){
        if(status=="success"){
            // window.location.href='phpToICS.php';
            // document.location.href='phpToICS.php';
            console.log(data);
            jAlert("Exported Succesfully","Success");
        }else if(status=="error"){
            jAlert("Error EXPORT Failed","Failure");
        }
      }
      );
}
```

Comment: read this one [.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @Pavlo, I see my data response is good, but missing the headers.     
So, I suppose I have to use dataType, or dataFilter to set the headers, but how? I don't see an example with attachment: header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

Comment: `header` is not required, but `data` must be, according to the example you should pass your variables into `data` property like: `data: { Bid:Bid, bid:bid, pax:pax, bType:type, timeStamp:timeStamp, stampEnd:stampEnd, timeIn:timeIn },` and define your `dataType`

Comment: @Pavlo, I tried many possible options, combinations also from here :http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp so far, at least my code give the success data that is supposed to be. But when I define a datatype like this       },"jsonp");
} it doesn't work. and I don't know where to put the data:{Bid:Bid,... Isn't what I have correct? It works in other ajax calls I use. ?

Comment: Also, you can see how it works here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976627/posting-json-with-jquery-ajax-to-php and use search in stackoverflow

Comment: @Pavlo, Thanks Pavlo, and which data type do I have to use: dataType: 'script', ? I tried all options, and none work. the console.log(data) gives me the correct results. It just doesn't trigger the file to get saved on return.

Comment: I also tried this: data: { Bid:Bid, bid:bid, pax:pax, bType:type, timeStamp:timeStamp, stampEnd:stampEnd, timeIn:timeIn }, but the script stops working, the same thing when I do datatype: function(data,status){... } or datatype: function(response,type){... }