# How can I pass a variable from JSON to PHP?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, session-variables

I'm using JSON to produce some data on Wordpress which I need to store in a PHP session variable. Here's the current setup that I'm messing around with but having no luck:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    $.ajax({
    url: 'url', 
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    data: {foo: 145},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
        }
    });  
});
```

and the PHP:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['bar'] = $_POST['foo'];
```

I can see the data in the console but nothing will display when I echo my sesh var. Using vardump returns an empty array. Where am I going wrong here?

(I realize there are plenty of other questions just like this, but believe me, I've tried them all - nada.)

Comment: you can't really set a php variable with javascript. When you send data over to your ajax script thats when the data becomes exposed to PHP, but you cannot set a variable from data returned back from the ajax call to a php variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976627/posting-json-with-jquery-ajax-to-php

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** You can't use javascript to store server side variables.

You must save the $_SESSION var in the PHP script that this AJAX calls. Which you have put URL?? In WordPress you can use JQuery to call a special hook which can be caught he functions.php that handles all AJAX.

There's info about this everywhere, see solution to this answer:
[Using AJAX in a WordPress plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855846/using-ajax-in-a-wordpress-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set a global variable for both languages and then transfer them via javascript you could do this on every page using php includes.